# Using a variable defined in an If statement?

Tags: java

Sorry if this sounds dumb, but I can't seem to figure out how to use the variable that I defined in the If statements.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);



        //Prompt for Enchantment Type
        System.out.println("Armor/Tool/Weapon");

        //Wait for response
        String input1 = scanner.nextLine();

        if(input1 == "Armor"){
            int type = 0;
        }
        else if(input1 == "Tool"){
            int type = 1;
        }
        else if(input1 == "Weapon"){
            int type = 2;
        }
        else {
            int type = 3;
        }

        //This is where I need to access the type int
        if(type == 1){

        }
    }
}
```

I can't figure out how to use the type string outside of it's block. I know that I'm supposed to read on scope and stuff, but I'd really like someone to just explain it to me.

Comment: @jlordo Definitely a problem here, but not the question being asked.

Comment: @thegrinner: Yes, I saw the code and marked duplicate without seeing the other problem...

Comment: upvoted as it seems to have cleared this for more than one person, looking at comments ! who reads all the old questions !

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use variables outside an `if-statement` then you need to declare it outside the `if-statement`.

Also you don't use `==` to compare `String` objects for contents equality, that only compares their `identity`. Use the `.equals()` or `.equalsIgnoreCase()` method instead.

Make everything you can `final`, that way you know what you are dealing with.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        //Prompt for Enchantment Type
        System.out.println("Armor/Tool/Weapon");

        final int type;

        //Wait for response
        String input1 = scanner.nextLine();

        if("Armor".equalsIgnoreCase(input1)){
            type = 0;
        }
        else if("Tool".equalsIgnoreCase(input1)){
            int type = 1;
        }
        else if("Weapon".equalsIgnoreCase(input1)){
            type = 2;
        }
        else {
            type = 3;
        }

        //This is where I need to access the String type
        if(type == 1){

        }
    }
}
```

A better way to do this is to switch on an `Enum` type.

```
public enum Item
{
    ARMOR,
    TOOL,
    WEAPON
}
```

Then you can convert your `input1` into the `Item` enum and switch on that.

```
final Item item = Item.valueOf(input1.toUpperCase());

switch(item) {
   case(ARMOR):
     // do stuff here 
     break;
   case(TOOL):
     // do stuff here 
     break;
   case(WEAPON):
     // do stuff here 
     break;
   default:
     // do something with unrecognized input
```

This removes the `magic numbers` that you have in your program right now.

Comment: +1 Perhaps a good time to switch on a String.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Only from Java 7 on.

Answer (score 3):

1. Declare the variable outside of the `if`'s scope
2. Use `.equals` to compare strings

Fixed code:

```
String input1 = scanner.nextLine();
int type; // scope

if(input1.equals("Armor")){
    int type = 0;
}
else if(input1.equals("Tool")){
    int type = 1;
}
else if(input1.equals("Weapon")){
    int type = 2;
}
else {
    int type = 3;
}

//This is where I need to access the String type
if(type == 1){

}
```

Note that you can also use a `switch` statement (only in Java 7!):

```
switch(input1) {
case "Armor":
    type = 0;
    break;
case "Tool":
    type = 1;
    break;
...
```

Also, in your case you could try `indexOf`:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

List<String> types = Arrays.asList("Armor", "Tool", "Weapon");
int type = types.indexOf(input1);
if (type == -1) type = 3; // if it's not found
```

Comment: +1 for showing how it’s done in Java 7.

Answer (score 1):

You should define the `type` outside the `if` condition

```
    int type = 0;
    if(("Armor".equalsIgnoreCase(input1)){
        type = 0;
    }
    else if("Tool".equalsIgnoreCase(input1)){
        type = 1;
    }
    else if("Weapon".equalsIgnoreCase(input1)){
        type = 2;
    }
    else {
       type = 3;
    }

    if(type == 4) {

    }
```

Comment: _if loop_ ? No such thing...

Comment: sorry... corrected it

Answer (score 1):

The scope of a variable is within the block it is defined in. So define the variable out of if  blocks and use it.

```
int type = 0;
if(input1 == "Armor"){
}else if(input1 == "Tool"){
   type = 1;
 }
 else if(input1 == "Weapon"){
    type = 2;
  }
  else {
     type = 3;
  }
```

**Note:** Also use String `equals` method to compare strings instead of `==`. Equals method checks whether the content of two strings are same, whereas == checks for objects equality.

Update your if and else blocks something like this:

```
int type = 0;
if("Armor".equals(input1)){
}else if("Tool".equals(input1){
   type = 1;
 }
 else if("Weapon".equals(input1)){
    type = 2;
  }
  else {
     type = 3;
  }
```

Comment: No @captain, absolutely not.

Comment: @captain No. That is completely wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You are not supposed to access from out of scope.
Just declare it in one of the enclosing scopes.

Answer (score 0):

your code has multiple errors.

1. you should define the type variable outside of the loop
2. you should compare Strings with `equals`

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);



        //Prompt for Enchantment Type
        System.out.println("Armor/Tool/Weapon");

        //Wait for response
        String input1 = scanner.nextLine();
        int type;

        if(input1.equals("Armor")){
            type = 0;
        }
        else if(input1.equals("Tool")){
            type = 1;
        }
        else if(input1.equals("Weapon")){
            type = 2;
        }
        else {
            type = 3;
        }

        //This is where I need to access the String type
        if(type == 1){

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: FYI, for some reason the list markdown broke your code block. I fixed it with a paragraph tag.

Comment: You need to assign a value to `int type` when you create it, or else it will generate an error, later in that code.

Comment: @Vallentin no it doesn't

Comment: If you write `final int type` then it won't generate an error, but if you just only write `int type` then your IDE will throw "The local variable type may not have been initialized" at you, so yes!

Comment: my eclipse doesn't. and there is no case when it is uninitialised